# Manipulating environment variables in YAML

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have a YAML file like this:

```yaml
mykey: !!python/object/apply:os.getenv ["URL"]
myotherkey: myothervalue
...
```

What I would like to do is perform a simple string operation on the `URL`. This could either be in Python, using `replace()`:

```py
import os
os.getenv("URL").replace("onestring", "withanother")
```

or some other combination of Python function calls, or by running a shell command (e.g. `sed` or similar).

AIUI the result of `!!python/object/apply:os.getenv` cannot be passed to another Python function, neither is it possible to call a method on the result of `!!python/object/apply:os.getenv`.

If I use `new:exec` instead of `apply:`, like this:

```yaml
mykey: !!python/object/new:exec ["import os; os.getenv('URL').replace('onestring', 'withanother')"]
myotherkey: myothervalue
...
```

then I believe the result of `new:exec ...` will not be stored in `mykey`.

Is this correct? Is there some other way to perform more complex operations within the YAML file, and store them in a key?

Comment: Do you have control over the Python code loading the YAML? This would be vastly simpler to implement with custom constructors in the loading process. You could also use a templating engine which is what most heavy YAML users do because YAML has not been designed for this and while it's generally possible to do, it is very unflexible.

Comment: You're totally right, but unfortunately I don't have arbitrary control over the YAML loading process. In this case, the YAML file is configuration for [`mkdocs`](https://www.mkdocs.org/), which does the loading.